# which physical volume does my logical volume use

Tags: lvm

I have a volume group which is made of many disks. (actually 2 but there could be more)

one disk (PV) is at risk an I would like to move LV that are on this disk on another one.

I know I can `pvmove -n /dev/myvg/mylv1 /dev/disk1 /dev/disk3`

So I would like to know which LV(s) are on a specific PV, how do I do that ?

thanks everyone for reading, cheers from a sunny island.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a `pvdisplay -m /dev/disk1`. The `Physical Segments` list will indicate which (parts of) logical volumes are located on that physical volume.

Alternatively, `lvdisplay -m /dev/myvg/mylv1` will show a list of `Segments`, indicating all the PVs containing any parts of that LV.